# opening a page without query string error in jsp

Tags: jsp

so, I have two JSP pages lets say first.jsp and second.jsp
now in page first.jsp i have 3 links.
all the three links are refering to second.jsp with some query string lets say second.jsp?s=one

now in second page I am getting this String 's' and shows result as:

```
String st=request.getParameter("s");

if(st.equals("one")){

}
if(st.equals("two"))
{

}
if(st.equals("three"))
{

}
```

suppose i clicked first link and reached on second.jsp?s=one page.
now in URL, if I remove query string and hit enter then it shows null pointer exception error.

how can I resolve this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for null before using the object. Something like this:

```
if (st == null){
  return WhatEverYouWantToReturn;
}
else{
    if(st.equals("one")){ ... }
    if(st.equals("two")){ ... }
    if(st.equals("three")){ ... }
}
```

If you call the .equals() on a null object, you will get a null pointer exception.

Comment: i already tried this technique but it doesn't work.......
it again shows error at line

    `if(st.equals("one")){
    
    }`

Comment: You have to make sure, you do not call the st.equals in case st is null with for example else-structure. Modified the answer to be more explicit.